# @Value в клиентском приложении Spring

Tags: spring, gui, rest

Есть приложение, написанное на SWT/JFace. Оно отображает данные, полученные с помощью spring'овского RestTemplate. URL для подключения должно брать из файла application.properties (его местоположение верное). Но не берет.

Помогите чайнику разобраться, что нужно сделать, чтобы можно было использовать аннотацию @Value.

Я пытаюсь использовать следующее, чтобы загрузить этот параметр:

```
public class Connect {

private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

@Value("#{rest}")
private String url;
///остальной код ...
}
```

Приложение стартует так:

```
public static void main(String ... args)
{
    SpringApplication.run(MainConfig.class, args);
    MyApp app = new MyApp();
    app.setBlockOnOpen(true);
    app.open();
    Display.getCurrent().dispose();
}
```

MainConfig выглядит так:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan("example")
public class MainConfig{ }
```

В application.properties, соответственно, одна строчка со значением rest.

При старте приложения поле url имеет значение null.

Знаю, что ошибаюсь, но не могу понять, где именно.
От spring'а мне требуются лишь RestTemplate (который прекрасно работает без 
        `SpringApplication.run(MainConfig.class, args);`)  и получение значения поля из конфиг. файла, ради чего и затеялась возня с MainConfig'ом и пр.

Как наиболее необременительно для приложения (желательно без `SpringApplication.run(MainConfig.class, args);)`) воспользоваться преимуществами аннотации @Value?

В application.properties находится строка

```
rest = http://localhost:8080/cont
```

Comment: Класс `Connect` кто и как создает?

Comment: Он создается при создании контролов MyApp и активно используется в виджетах.
Т.е. при app.open()

Comment: имеется в виду же экземпляр класса Connect?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ваш класс Connect должен являться бином с точки зрения контейнера.
2. Синтаксис для плейсхолдеров должен быть таким: `${rest}` (Через `#` указываются ESpL-выражения).

Comment: Сейчас я пробую сделать так:
@Component
public class Connect {

@Value("${rest}")
private String url;

Значение url остается null, но если вместо $ использовать #, то вылетает ошибка

Comment: @lester какая ошибка?

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String example.loader.Loader.restURLNeededFiles; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'rest' cannot be found on object of type

Comment: @lester неправильно понимаете. Стектрейс вам четко сообщает, что не может интерпретировать SPeL-выражение. Но вам оно и не нужно, вам нужен плейсхолдер через `$`. Почему у вас там `null` - это вопрос отдельный. Вероятнее всего, неправильно оформлен properties-файл.

Comment: а РlaceHolderConfigurer загружен ?

Comment: наверное, нет, но строки вида

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    } в MainConfig не помогают. Разве @EnableAutoConfiguration не сделает все за меня?

На серверном приложении тоже используются @Value с SpringBoot, но там все работает просто

Comment: @lester добавьте то, что советует @argamidon

{    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}

Comment: @lester посмотри [в эту тему][1], может, поможет, лично у меня была проблема в неправильном указанном символе. # вместо $ - всё остальное ок


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/396460/java-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-property-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-propertysource

Comment: @a_gura, @argamidon -  
после добавления

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer props = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        props.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        return props;
    }
в логах появилось Loading properties file from class path resource [application.properties]. null по-прежнему на месте. Не понимаю, почему это нужно писать. Разве SpringBoot не должен делать это? Такое чувство, что @EnableAutoConfiguration не работае

Comment: @lester а что у вас в файле `application.properties`?